# WP8.1 PlayerFramework and FLV playback support

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, media-player, flv

I'm trying to add `flv` support to my Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML) app. The idea is to retrieve multiple urls (containing 30-minute segments of a video) from a (single) call to an api (in this case, Twitch API) and use the resulting links for playback.

The problem is WP has [no native support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for `.flv` files, so I can't seem to play the files using [Microsoft's Media Player Framework](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/).

I've dug around a little and others seem to be suggesting (albeit non-trivially) creating a `MediaStreamSource` and connecting the links (or even writing my own container), though it seems like a huge hassle.

Has anyone come across any helpful libraries or any solutions to this problem? Would prefer not to have to download each segment to the phone (for obvious reasons) and simply create a 'stream' if possible.

**Note**: If it's any help, according to [this thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Twitch/comments/1wnd1i/twitch_vods/cf3rnm1), the `flv` files from Twitch are `h264/aac content` (which **IS** a supported video codec from the link above).

**Example (single) link returned from the api call to Twitch:**
http://media-cdn.twitch.tv/store92.media67/archives/2014-10-12/live_user_riotgames_1413100271.flv

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution? As even I'm also creating a Win10 app on winrt which needs to play .flv and other video formats and couldnt get it running with mediaExtensionManager.

Comment: Unfortunately not... I started looking at adding it myself to phonesm but didn't get too far in before Twitch added `HLS` playback for vods (so I didn't need `flv` anymore)